# Is there a way of end-to-end authentication of Hex packages?

Tags: erlang, elixir, digital-signature, package-managers

I was looking for a way to cryptographically verify the integrity and authenticity of packages downloaded through the Hex package manager in Elixir. So far I didn't find anything.

Some package managers support digital signature systems like OpenPGP to make sure, that the code installed on the target system is exactly identical to the code produced by the package's author and therefore disincentivize attacks trying to alter data on the central data store which holds thousands of packages.

Is there any kind of support for this in Hex, the popular package manager for Elixir and Erlang?

Comment: I think you should put in a feature request with hex for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hex does not currently support user-signed packages. A few different package managers have tried to implement user-signing but none have been completely successful in the sense that it is easy enough to use that all publishers are required to sign their packages and all consumers are required to verify the signature authenticity.

The web of trust (PGP-like) approach is problematic because you have to establish a network of trust which is a high barrier of entry – do you have to physically meet other developers or somehow have them verify who you are so they can sign your key before publishing your first package?

The centralized trust (X.509-like) approach is also problematic. If the central repository Hex.pm issues certificates, then compromising Hex.pm will also compromise the user-signed packages which is what we are trying to prevent.

We have made [proposals for signing packages](https://gist.github.com/ericmj/0ad5d6773c508a5b4a50c870934b39b7), we have evaluated [other approaches](https://theupdateframework.github.io/) and are following and participating in [ongoing discussions](https://github.com/package-community/discussions/issues/5) on how to solve this problem.

Even though Hex does not support user-signed packages we do other things to verify the authenticity of packages. The package contents are checksummed and included in the [package tarball](https://github.com/hexpm/specifications/blob/master/package_tarball.md) and stored on the server. The package checksum is printed when the users builds the package and can be verified against the package in the repository. Checksums are included in the repository index which is signed by the [Hex.pm private key](https://hex.pm/docs/public_keys). Downloaded packages are verified against the checksum in the index and if the package is locked it is also verified against the checksum in the lock.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I would recommend an OpenPGP-based solution because it is an established Internet standard, allows for hierarchical (like X.509 PKI) and graph-based trust delegation and also individual out-of-band management of identity authenticity (e.g. Keybase). It is also successfully used to secure other package managers (e.g. APT, Yum) since many years. Also there are lots of tech people with experience in OpenPGP implementations like GnuPG. Identity management is and will probably stay hard, I see no way around it.

Comment: Perhaps a link to this discussion can also be added: https://github.com/hexpm/hex/issues/52